# Kubernetes image update breaks pods and have to kill deployments

Tags: kubernetes

So my setup on kubernetes is basically an external nginx load balancer that sends traffic for virtual hosts across the nodes.

The network runs all docker containers, 10 instances of a front end pod which is a compiled angular app, 10 instances of a pod that has two containers, a “built” image of a symfony app with a phpfpm container dedicated for each pod, an external mysql server on the local network which runs a basic docker container, 10 cdn pods which simply run an nginx server to pick up static content requests, 10 pods that run a socket chat application via nginx, a dedicated network of open vidu servers, and it also runs php fpm pods for multiple cron jobs.

All works fine and dandy until I say update the front end image and do an update to the cluster. The pods all update no problem but I end up with a strange issue of pages not loading, or partially loading, or somehow a request for the backend pods ending up not loading the http request or somehow loading from frontend pods. It’s really quite random.

The only way to get it back up again is to destroy every deployment and fire them up again and I’ve no idea what is causing it. Once it’s all restarted it all works again.

Just looking for idea on what it could be , anyone experienced this behaviour before?

Comment: You need to provide more debug info.

Comment: ThTs the thing there is no debug info, there are no errors from kubernetes it’s all running, the only logs are from the load balancer saying it couldn’t route the traffic when it happens. But then it all comes back after restarting it all. No other errors to provide

Comment: When you restart the deployment, and then deploy again, do you use the updated image or do you use the old one? Can you share the configuration files that you use for your deployment, regarding the old version as well as the updated one?